# How can i extract a zip having password and created by winzip using python?

Tags: python-3.x, zip

I have a zip file ( created by winzip ) which i want to extract with python. The problem is zipfile module of Python only extracts zip files which have PKWARE password protection, so i can't extract the one created by winzip.

**Is there any other module which can do this task for me ?**